# Make form inputs with type 'text' have a gray background

Tags: html, css, input, css-selectors

Is this the correct way to solve this simple request?

input [type="text"]{ background: gray;}

When i refresh my html, the input box that I am targeting doesn't change.

Here is the html mark up:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: the input tag does not have a closing slash in HTML. It's not an error but it's not needed, ignored by browsers and not called for in the HTML documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remove the space after `input` else the style is applied to `[type="text"]` contained within `input`

```
input[type="text"] {
    background: gray;
}
```

---

**A bit of extra information**

```
<a href="#" class="button">Text</a>
```

The anchor element above has a class of .button so to make the text red you would need the following:

```
a.button {
    //No space
    color: red;
}
```

If you now add a space between the `a` and `.button` selector this would no longer work because you're essentially saying "Look inside the `a` element for  `.button`".

```
a .button {
    //Space
    color: red;
}
```

However the below would work because `.button` is now nested inside the `a` element.

```
<a href="#"><span class="button">Text</span></a>
```

---

I've also attached the jsfiddle by [zfrisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3700849/zfrisch):
https://jsfiddle.net/0kcvb3d6/

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Detailed Example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input[type=text] {
      width: 200px;
      display: block;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      background-color: gray;
      color: white;
    }
    input[type=button] {
      width: 120px;
      margin-left: 80px;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="input" action="" method="post">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="Your Name" size="20">

    <input type="button" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```